# c making variable argument required

Tags: c++, unix, g++, variadic-functions

I have a function as

```
AddSprintf(char* , ... )
```

I want to make compile time error if somebody is calling it without two arguments. 
Currently if somebody is calling like

```
AddSprintf("hello")
```

it works. But I want to disable calling like this. 
Is there any way using g++ I can force passing of argument ?

Comment: Adding a second  argument is not an option?

Comment: @BoPersson no. What I want to make sure there is atleast one member in  va_list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overload AddSprintf:

```
void AddSprintf(const char* , ... ) {}
void AddSprintf(const char*);
```

Then you get a weird error message when compiling `AddSprintf("hello")`

But keep in mind that with C++11 you should use variadic templates because they are typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
AddSprintf(char* , char*, ... )
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really. The dots stand for "zero or more arguments", and there is no way of knowing if there is any arguments. Except maybe using assembler and do some checking of the stack pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As 0A0D says, it's variadic - by definition, the compiler is going to be fine with it. If you want it to fail at compiler time, you may have to pull tricks - for example, if you're unit testing, have code that makes the function fail with one argument call, so that new programmers will know they can't do that.

That said, why are you trying to do this? There may be a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the same name, then you can use variadic macro:

```
#define AddSprintf(X,...) AddSprintf(X,__VA_ARGS__)
```

But be very careful with this solution, as `AddSprintf` would work first as text replacement in preprocessing stage. Then only it would be a function.